# Unable to send parameters from HTML/JS form to URL

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I am new to front end development, but this seems to be a pretty simple task.

I need to take a value input by a user in an HTML/JS form and then append that value to the end of a public server URL and show a specific visualisation. To explain it further, here's a sample viz that I created. 
https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/subhayan#!/vizhome/Book1_1826/Sheet1

Now, it is possible to filter this visualisation by appending `&Name=A` or `&Name=B` at the end. (You can see for yourself [here](https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/subhayan#!/vizhome/Book1_1826/Sheet1&Name=A), and [here](https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/subhayan#!/vizhome/Book1_1826/Sheet1&Name=B).

I have even written a simple HTML form, but I'm unable to append the user input to the end of the action URL of the form.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: if the form contain the Name field you can use the GET method to post the form to the url you want to append the Name

Comment: Hashbang and data from form are very different words. `#!` is something for compatibility between older browser and dynamically changed content. About hashbangs you can read at [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript function to craft the url and then redirect:

HTML (inside form):

```
<input type="button" onclick="craft_url(this.form);" value="Go">
```

JavaScript:

```
function craft_url(f){
  var x = f.a.value; //Being 'a' the name of the field
  var url = 'https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/subhayan#!/vizhome/Book1_1826/Sheet1' + '&Name=' + x;
  document.location = url;
}
```